# get rid of value from combobox while loading the page

Tags: javascript, xpages

I created a xpage but while reloading the page the comboboxes in this page is taking the first value from the database in the select2picker comboBox how could I solve this problem?

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
    <xp:this.value>
        <![CDATA[XSP.addOnLoad(
            function() { 
                x$( "#{id:listBoxProperties}").on("change", function(e) { 
                    XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:dataView1}" ) 
                })
            }
        );
        ]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>

    <xp:comboBox id="listBoxProperties" 
                        value="#{sessionScope.searchVwCompanyOwner}">
        <xp:selectItems>
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var listvalues = new Array();
            try { listvalues = (getSettingsList("Global.Entity"));
    listvalues;
            } catch(e) {print("ERROR in Company: " + e);}}]]>
            </xp:this.value>
        </xp:selectItems>
    </xp:comboBox>
    <bx:select2PickerCombo id="select2PickerCombo1"
                        for="listBoxProperties" allowClearing="true"
                        placeHolder="-company Owner-" binding="#{listBoxProperties}">

    </bx:select2PickerCombo>
```

this code is working for one time page reload but for more than one time refreshing it is taking the first value from the database.

Comment: Show the code what you've tried so far, please .. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use **viewScope** variable instead of sessionScope variable:

```
value="#{viewScope.searchVwCompanyOwner}"
```

SessionScope variable keeps the value for whole user session including page refresh whereas viewScope variable exists for current XPage only.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two other options:

1. Change the control to a single value listbox, or,
2. Within your calculation, or as a separate entry, add a blank value '' as the first value.